# java sessions - when does a session actually gets created?

Tags: java, session, servlets

my code,

```
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
//          Details.l.info(" 1>>>>session ID is : " + session.getId());

        Details.l.info("["+this.getClass()+"]"+"request from "+request.getRemoteHost());

        if(session==null){
            session = request.getSession(true);
            Details.l.info("["+this.getClass()+"]"+"Session Created!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#####$@@@@");
            Details.l.info(" 2>>>>>session ID is : " + session.getId());
        }  

        Details.l.info(" 3>>>>>session ID is : " + session.getId());
    //  System.out.println("session ID is : " + session.getId());
        Details DTO = new Details(request);
        String loc = DTO.findMyLocation(); 
                session.invalidate();
```

here, i am creating a session at the very beginning of the servlet with a logic that if the session already exists, then give hat session ID for that particular user or if a session does not exist for this particular user, please create a new session and then give the new session ID, here the new session is created inside the IF condition and i have tested in all possible ways (i have used two different systems and tried hitting to the servlet on one system too) but the control never gets into this loop where the session is getting created. but i see every time i hit to the servlet i get a new session ID!!! can someone please exlain this behavior of my servlet?? i am very new to sessions and servlets!! 
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: because of session.invalidate();

Comment: @cproinger - if i am invalidatiog the session every time for each user, then why am i not going into the if condition and creating the session on every request?

Comment: So, the problem is that a session already exists, every time with a different ID, when hitting this servlet? Is that right? How do you invoke this servlet? What happens before this servlet is invoked? Any JSP displayed?

Comment: @JB Nizet, EXACTLY!! this is wat is happening, yes i have a JSP , that is where a trigger to the servlet, that is the button exists. i just observed that my JSP is itself creating a session and then hitting to the servlet!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSPs implicitely create a session, unless session is set to false in the page directive:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

That's why your servlet always sees an already existing session. Simply enter the address of the servlet in the browser address bar (provided the code you posted is in the `doGet()` method), instead of going through the JSP to invoke it, and you should see the servlet create a new session.

EDIT: note that the spec says about this session attribute that it can be used to specify that the JSP doesn't participate in the session. Nothing guarantees that no session will be created when invoking the JSP. Only that, if you try to access the session from this JSP, you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use request.getSession(true) to always create a session.

Comment: okay, so will this happen if i create a session everytime a request comes to the servlet ?? - user one logs on to my page and clicks a button, then my servlet creates a session for this user and starts a task. while this task is going, another user, user 2 logs on to this page from a different computer and clicks this button (while the user 1's session is still happening) will this user 2 get a new session a start the similar task?? will these two tasks be synchronized??? (the task the user 1 us doing and the task the user 2 is doing)??

Comment: For each user one session will be created. It can work concurrently.

Comment: yeah, theoritically i have read all these things till now. i am not able to experiance it in real. something is happening and the two tasks are getting jammed

Comment: If you are using same browser for simulating two users, It will be counted as one user based on sessionid cookie.

Comment: no no, i am using two different computers to test this case